# omit extra quotes in parameter of STORED PROCEDURE in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

This is procedure I am calling using call below:

```
CALL abc('01-04-2011','14-04-2014','28,29,36,37,38','33,34,35,41,42,43')
```

But the problem is that a query mentioned below is taking param1 in **quotes** which is not producing desired results.

```
SELECT ID FROM some_table WHERE CODE IN (param1);
```

(param1 is '28,29,36,37,38' here)

I want the query to be like `SELECT ID FROM some_table WHERE CODE IN (28,29,36,37,38)`

but it is run as `SELECT ID FROM some_table WHERE CODE IN (*'28,29,36,37,38'*)`

How can I omit these extra quotes which are due to VARCHAR datatype of param1.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
SELECT ID FROM some_table WHERE CODE IN (REPLACE(param1,"'",''));
```

Comment: REPLACE won't help as QUOTES are intoduced implicitly at run time and are not the part of param1 itself